# Reading CSV file to 2D double array in C

Tags: c, arrays, csv

I need to write a program to parse a large CSV file (approx. 2000*2000) in C and store in the form of a double[] [] array. I wrote a program, which seems to work for small files (i checked for a 4*4 csv file), but for large files it gives me incorrect results.(as in the number of rows and columns are wrong and the program crashes after that).

This is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main (void)
{
    int rowMaxIndex,columnMaxIndex;
    double **mat;
    double *matc;
    int i,j,idx,len;
    char part[5000];
    char *token;
    char *temp;
    char *delim = ",";
    double var;
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("X1_CR2_new1.csv","r");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // count loop
    rowMaxIndex = 0;
    columnMaxIndex = 0;
    while(fgets(part,5000,fp) != NULL){
        token = NULL;
        token=strtok(part,delim);
                    while(token != NULL){
                       if(rowMaxIndex==0)
                       {
                       columnMaxIndex++;}
                       token=strtok(NULL,delim);
        }
        rowMaxIndex++;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    printf("Number of rows is %d, and Number of columns is %d", rowMaxIndex, columnMaxIndex);
    // allocate the matrix

    mat = malloc(rowMaxIndex * sizeof(double*));

    for (i = 0; i < rowMaxIndex; i++)
    {
        mat[i] = malloc(columnMaxIndex * sizeof(double));
        }
        fclose(fp);
}
    // rewind the file to the beginning. The rewind(fp) wasnt working so closed and reopened file.

{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("X1_CR2_new1.csv","r");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // read loop
    i = j = 0;
    while(fgets(part,5000,fp)!=NULL)
    {    
        token=strtok(part,delim);
        j=0;
        while (token != NULL){
              mat[i][j]=atof(token);
              //printf("\n %f", mat[i][j]);
              token=strtok(NULL,delim);
              j++;
          }
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n The value of mat 1, 2 is %f", mat[1][0]);  //print some element to check
    free(mat);
    fclose(fp);
}    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try to debug your code: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you data has 2000 columns but your `fgets()` reads at most 4999 characters.  Isn't there a chance your data is wider than 4999 chars?  You should probably check that each line read in ends with a newline (except perhaps the last line in the file).

As an aside, you don't need to reopen the file--just `rewind()` it.

Comment: Or, simpler, use POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html),
which always returns a complete line unless it cannot allocate enough memory.

Comment: Thanks. changed to 20000 chars and it works fine now. However, tried rewind() but it did not go back to start of the file. I dont know why. Getline is not included in my default package so did not use.